# How to call function getInfoWindowEvent(marker)

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

As with many people who find themselves at StackOverflow, I am somewhat new to Javascript and the Google Maps API. I am stumped by how to call the code posted by jamesaharvey a few years back.

I have a version of my project uses infowindows but they must be closed manually. This is a much more elegant way of doing it. I just can't get it to work. I am using the following

```
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

function getInfoWindowEvent(marker) {
    infowindow.close()
    infowindow.setContent("huh?");
    infowindow.open(map, marker);
}
```

I have multiple markers that display properly.

```
var MAPA = new google.maps.Marker({position: {lat: 12.3400, lng: -12.3450}, map: map, title: 'A Marker'});
var MAPB = new google.maps.Marker({position: {lat: 12.3450, lng: -12.3455}, map: map, title: 'B Marker'});
var MAPC = new google.maps.Marker({position: {lat: 12.3460, lng: -12.3460}, map: map, title: 'C Marker'});
```

It is my assumption that I need to call add a listener for each marker to call getInfoWindowEvent when the marker is clicked. Something like this.

```
MAPA.addListener('click', getInfoWindowEvent(MAPA));
MAPB.addListener('click', getInfoWindowEvent(MAPB));
MAPC.addListener('click', getInfoWindowEvent(MAPC));
```

I know I am missing something along the way here. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The `.addListener` function's second argument needs to be a function pointer, not (necessarily) a function.  Either use a function that takes the `MouseEvent` argument, like this:

```
MAPA.addListener('click', getInfoWindowEvent);
```

Or return a function from the function (a function in the second argument will be executed and its return value used as the click function):

```
function getInfoWindowEvent(marker) {
  return function(evt) {
    infowindow.close()
    infowindow.setContent("huh?<br>"+this.getPosition().toUrlValue(6));
    infowindow.open(map, marker);
  }
}
```

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/d28wxgda/)

**code snippet:**

```js
function initialize() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(
    document.getElementById("map_canvas"), {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(12.34, -12.34),
      zoom: 14,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });

  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

  map.addListener('click', function(evt) {
    infowindow.close()
  });

  function getInfoWindowEvent(marker) {
    return function(evt) {
      infowindow.close()
      infowindow.setContent("huh?<br>" + this.getPosition().toUrlValue(6));
      infowindow.open(map, marker);
    }
  }

  var MAPA = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: {
      lat: 12.3400,
      lng: -12.3450
    },
    map: map,
    title: 'A Marker'
  });
  var MAPB = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: {
      lat: 12.3450,
      lng: -12.3455
    },
    map: map,
    title: 'B Marker'
  });
  var MAPC = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: {
      lat: 12.3460,
      lng: -12.3460
    },
    map: map,
    title: 'C Marker'
  });

  MAPA.addListener('click', getInfoWindowEvent(MAPA));
  MAPB.addListener('click', getInfoWindowEvent(MAPB));
  MAPC.addListener('click', getInfoWindowEvent(MAPC));

}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize);
```

```css
html,
body,
#map_canvas {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<div id="map_canvas"></div>
```